# How do I send an HTML Form in an Email .. not just MAILTO

Tags: html, forms

I have an HTML form for people to fill out, and I want it so when they click the submit button, it will just send the email, not bring up their email and ask them to send the message themselves.

When I use:

```
<form action="MAILTO:emailaddress@email.com"... >
```

All that does is open up a new window and populates the body of the email, but I want it to just send an email.

And is there a way to format the output of what the email will look like? Instead of just a list of  the field names and the entered value.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know that what you want to do is possible. From my understanding, sending an email from a web form requires a server side language to communicate with a mail server and send messages. Are you running PHP or ASP.NET? [ASP.NET Example](http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/11/30/ASPNET-Contact-Form.aspx) [PHP Example](http://www.kirupa.com/web/php_contact_form.htm)

Comment: You'll need to send the email using a server-side technology, which language/framework are you using?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/html-forms-in-html-emails/

Comment: any other no-backend options? or very easy to deploy for front end engineer options?  the option below with google script seems unsecure although very fast to implement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually use ASP C# to send my emails now, with something that looks like :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Form.Count > 0)
    {
        string formEmail = "";
        string fromEmail = "from@email.com";
        string defaultEmail = "default@email.com";

        string sendTo1 = "";

        int x = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Form.Keys.Count; i++)
        {
            formEmail += "<strong>" + Request.Form.Keys[i] + "</strong>";
            formEmail += ": " + Request.Form[i] + "<br/>";
            if (Request.Form.Keys[i] == "Email")
            {
                if (Request.Form[i].ToString() != string.Empty)
                {
                    fromEmail = Request.Form[i].ToString();
                }
                formEmail += "<br/>";
            }

        }
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage myMsg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

        try
        {
            myMsg.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(defaultEmail));
            myMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            myMsg.Body = formEmail;
            myMsg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(fromEmail);
            myMsg.Subject = "Sent using Gmail Smtp";
            smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtpClient.Port = 587;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("testing@gmail.com", "pward");

            smtpClient.Send(defaultEmail, sendTo1, "Sent using gmail smpt", formEmail);

        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            debug.Text += ee.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example using gmail as the smtp mail sender. Some of what is in here isn't needed, but it is how I use it, as I am sure there are more effective ways in the same fashion.

Answer (score 67):

## > *2023 Answer* = *Easy* Way using GMail (*5 Mins*)

We had a *similar* challenge to solve yesterday, and we solved it using a Google Apps Script!

#### Send Email From an HTML Form *Without* a Backend (*Server*) via Google!

The solution takes ***5 mins*** to implement and I've documented with ***step-by-step instructions***: [https://github.com/nelsonic/**html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server**](https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server#how)

### Brief Overview

#### A. Using the sample script, deploy a Google App Script

Deploy the sample script as a Google Spreadsheet APP Script:
[**google-script-just-email.js**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qzEn_0cgq3KdxsGll8Ewv_jlVmlZstS6eReAXECMY2c/edit#gid=0)

[image: 3-script-editor-showing-script]

> ***remember*** to set the `TO_ADDRESS` in the script to where ever you want the emails to be sent.
> and copy the **APP URL** so you can use it in the next step when you ***publish the script***.

#### B. Create your HTML Form and Set the `action` to the App URL

Using the sample `html` file:
[**index.html**](https://github.com/nelsonic/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server/blob/master/index.html#L11)
create a basic form.

[image: 7-html-form]

> **remember** to paste your **APP URL** into the form `action` in the HTML form.

#### C. Test the HTML Form in your Browser

Open the HTML Form in your Browser, Input some data & submit it!

[image: html form]

Submit the form. You should see a confirmation that it was sent:
[image: form sent]

Open the inbox for the email address you set (*above*)

[image: email received]

## Done.

> ***Everything*** about this is ***customisable***, you can *easily*
> ***style/theme*** *the* ***form*** with your favourite **CSS** Library
> *and* ***Store*** the submitted **data** in a **Google Spreadsheet**
> for *quick* analysis.
> The ***complete instructions*** are available on **GitHub**:
> [https://github.com/nelsonic/**html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server**](https://github.com/nelsonic/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server)

Comment: Can we use this technique if we have to send some files from the HTML form to an email address ?

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your answer so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See the [documentation on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images, as well as [mcve].

Answer (score 23):

You are making sense, but you seem to misunderstand the concept of sending emails.

HTML is parsed on the client side, while the e-mail needs to be sent from the server. You cannot do it in pure HTML. I would suggest writing a PHP script that will deal with the email sending for you.

Basically, instead of the MAILTO, your form's action will need to point to that PHP script. In the script, retrieve the values passed by the form (in PHP, they are available through the `$_POST` superglobal) and use the email sending function (`mail()`).

Of course, this can be done in other server-side languages as well. I'm giving a PHP solution because PHP is the language I work with.

A simple example code:

form.html:

```
<form method="post" action="email.php">
    <input type="text" name="subject" /><br />
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
</form>
```

email.php:

```
<?php
    mail('youremail@example.com', $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message']);
?>
<p>Your email has been sent.</p>
```

Of course, the script should contain some safety measures, such as checking whether the $_POST valies are at all available, as well as additional email headers (sender's email, for instance), perhaps a way to deal with character encoding - but that's too complex for a quick example ;).

Comment: Thank you, looking at your example helps me quite a bit, I will be looking into php a little more now so I will be able to use it more