# How to send HTML form data by email to an email ID by using JavaScript, without using server-side language, without using email client securely?

Tags: javascript, html, email, security

How to send HTML form data by email to an email ID by using JavaScript and without using server-side language and without using email client securely? I do not want any email client to pop open on clicking submit.

Comment: what about
https://github.com/whiteout-io/smtpclient
http://emailjs.org/ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send an HTML Form in an Email .. not just MAILTO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449767/how-do-i-send-an-html-form-in-an-email-not-just-mailto)

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to send email by JavaScript:

```
 <textarea id="Body">
     Mail Content
 </textarea>
 <button onclick="sendMail();">Send</button>
```

SendMail function:

```
function sendMail() {
         var link = "mailto:me@example.com"
         + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
         + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
         + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('Body').value)
     ;

     window.location.href = link;
 }
```

You can call `SendMail()` function on submit.
Hope this help you.

Comment: hi, thank you but I don't want any client to open up, in this case client opens up. I want mail to be directly sent on clicking the form submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement basically says that you want to hit an smtp server directly and the mail should go from there.

This would mean that Javascript should support a way to send data to an smtp server.

The default way to talk to a smtp server is via TCP/IP (you can use telnet on a smtp server, usually on port 25).

Since Javascript does not support TCP/IP directly it is not possible to do it directly from Javascript.

This does not mean that

1. You cannot use a email service which provides rest interface
2. Write your own backend based on REST to relay it to an SMTP server
3. Have a backend which acts as a proxy to you incoming rest and translate it to a tcp/ip request and send it to the corresponding server and port

The above three methods seem to be the only ways I can think of to send a mail from Javascript.

Edit: There seems to be a TCPSocket https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCPSocket but it is not widely supported.

You might also want to look into flash, I don't know how long it will be widely supported though.

Comment: Flash will only connect to third-party servers that serve a `crossdomain.xml`, so you won't be able to connect to arbitrary SMTP servers that way. TCPSocket isn't available from web pages, assuming that's what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, I am not too sure about TCPSocket or Flash.

Answer (score 0):

It's very much deliberate that you aren't allowed to do this. If you could, everyone's browsers would be turned into infernal spam-spewing abuse machines.

From a web page, you can only choose between client-side mail, letting the user confirm what they're sending (and losing some proportion of respondants who aren't in a position to send mail), or a web-accessible server-side mail forwarder (either a third-party service or your own server in which case you have to work out the security yourself).