# Sending JSON data via email from SurveyJS

Tags: php, json, surveyjs

I have created a survey using SurveyJS and rather than store the results of my survey on the SurveyJS website I would like to email the results of anyone that takes the survey to my own email address.

I have never used JSON before so this is my first time. Any guidance would be helpful!

The HTML:

```
<div id="surveyContainer"></div>
<div id="surveyResult"></div>
```

JSON from SurveyJS:

```
<script>
    Survey
    .StylesManager
    .applyTheme("default");

    var json = {SURVEY DATA HIDDEN}

    window.survey = new Survey.Model(json);

    survey
    .onComplete
    .add(function (result) {
        document
        .querySelector('#surveyResult')
        .textContent = "Result JSON:\n" + JSON.stringify(result.data, null, 3);
    });

    $("#surveyContainer").Survey({model: survey});
</script>
```

Currently the results are displayed in the div with the ID of surveyResult. How can I not show them and send them in an email using PHP instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the sever side code then you need to check this thread - [Using HTML and PHP to send form data to an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927980/using-html-and-php-to-send-form-data-to-an-email/21381798)

If you are asking about the client side JavaScript - check these threads:
[How to send HTML form data by email to an email ID by using JavaScript, without using server-side language, without using email client securely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435012/how-to-send-html-form-data-by-email-to-an-email-id-by-using-javascript-without)
[How to send an email from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript)