# HTML Form Submitting and redirecting to another page after submission

Tags: html

I am building a website. I want to have a page where someone fills out their information and can click on the send button and it be emailed to me. After they click on the send button, I would like for them to be sent to a thank you page. How do I do that with HTML? TIA

Comment: thankyou page must be a php file, which will check customers input, send you an email and show html

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/7449823/ [How do I send an HTML Form in an Email ..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449767/how-do-i-send-an-html-form-in-an-email-not-just-mailto)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use PHP for the form to send an email to you, there is a lot of information about that. When you fill the form, the php script takes that information and then sends the email to whoever you set the script and redirects you to another page.

HTML

```
<form action="email_sent.php" method="post">
// Input values here
</form>
```

PHP

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// Message that the email was sent
echo "<div> <h2>Thank you!</h2> </div>";
```

More information about the send mail through php can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php I took the PHP send mail script from here

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I went to that page and am so confused! Is there any way you could email me?

Answer (score 1):

You can't send emails via HTML. I generally see two approaches how to do this:

### Client only

This is the simplest way if you have no control of the server (i.e., writing dynamic scripts such as PHP or ASP). You can use a [mailto link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/), which usually opens the default mail program, when the user opens it.

```html
<a href="mailto:you@yoursite.com">Send Mail</a>
```

The user has to fill the subject, body etc. in his mail program. This does not open a thank you page after sending.

If you use JavaScript, you can even dynamically add subject, body text etc. to the mailto link, so the mail program pre-fills these fields with whatever you have typed on the website. You can add an onclick-handler so it *also* jumps to a thank you page.

### Server Scripting

You can send your form as POST data to the server and use a script (such as PHP), that sends a mail and responses with the thank you page.