# I can't get my submit button to send an email, Ive tried several formats

Tags: html, forms, email, button, submit

I am using a form id= contact-form with a form loader. I have tried getting my email to submit with form action and html href however nothing has working this is what I am currently trying to get to work. any suggestions?

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:m_galvin1005@email.campbell.edu" >
<input type="submit" value="Send Email" /> 
</form>
```

I placed this form method inside of a form id. Not sure if thats where I am getting held up at

Comment: The `mailto:` tag is used to open a local email client. You can do some stuff to populate the subject and message but it will still just open a local email client. If you want to send an email you need to have your form post information to a server side language that can actually send the email.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send an HTML Form in an Email .. not just MAILTO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449767/how-do-i-send-an-html-form-in-an-email-not-just-mailto)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, browsers don't actually know how to send emails. The web browser only really knows how to render HTML, JS and CSS code into a visual experience.

PHP is a language that runs server-side, which you can use to tell a web server to send an email to whatever address you input.

Here's a good article on PHP Emailing: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/send-email/

It is important to note that this code REQUIRES a web-space or server to compile.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a very basic email form, having said this I think you are missing`post` argument in your form tag. The following should work

```
<form action="mailto:m_galvin1005@email.campbell.edu" method="post" enctype="text/plain" >
Name:<input type="text" name="Name">
Email:<input type="text" name="Email">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```