# create email form using html

Tags: html, forms, email

I want to create a HTML form to send email.
something like this: when the user enter name, email and message, press the send button and the message send to my email address.
I searched a lot. but I couldn't find anything useful.
thanks a lot

```
<form id="form" action="mailto:mail@mail.com" method="post">
     <p class="column col4"><label for="name">Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></p>
     <p class="column col4"><label for="email">E-mail:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></p>
     <p class="column col8"><label for="message">Message:</label><textarea rows="5" name="message" id="message"></textarea></p>
     <p class="column col8"><input class="button" type="submit" value="Send" /></p>
                        </form>
```

this doesn't work. after press send button the outlook opens and instead of message i get name=....&message=....

my server support php.

please help me

Comment: You need address that server-side. What backend technology are you using?

Comment: You can not send emails from an `html` form only. The form is needd only to collect the data. You need as @VojtechRuzicka say a server-side script as  by example `php`

Comment: You can't send email from an HTML file. Your form will simply open a new email message in the client's default mail program, *if* they have one installed... You need something as a backend. Someone on SW did manage to do this with a Google App Script as their "backend", you could check that out (Nelsonic's answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449767/how-do-i-send-an-html-form-in-an-email-not-just-mailto

Answer (score 2):

[`mailto:` as a form action is highly unreliable](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html), so much so that it is effectively unusable on the WWW.

You need to set the action to an HTTP (or, preferably, HTTPS) URL and then handle the form submission using a server side technology.

Reading form data and sending email is relatively trivial in any server side programming language. So you could start by seeing what your server supports along those lines and then just using that.

Alternatively, there are (or at least there were last time I looked) third party form mailer services which allow you to set the action to a URL hosted on their site.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send emails via HTML. You would need to submit the form to a page that can run code on the server. PHP might be a good choice for you.

email_form.html:

```
<html><body>
  <form action="send_email_to_minerva.php">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br />
    Email: <input type="email" name="email_address"><br />
    Message:<br /><textarea name="message"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
</body></html>
```

send_email_to_minerva.php:

```
<html><body>
  <?php
    // The message
    $name = $_GET["name"];
    $email_address = $_GET["email_address"];
    $message = $_GET["message"];
    $full_message = $name + '\n\r' + $email_address + '\n\r' + $message;
    $subject = 'Someone just emailed you from your own site';
    // Send
    mail('minerva@example.com', $subject, $full_message);
  ?>

  Your mail has been sent.
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, after I press send button I see the page with the content of send_mail_to_minerva.php
but i want to be at the current page

Comment: how can i return to my previous page?

Comment: `header('Location: email_form.php');`