# Sending form data via html

Tags: html, forms, email

so I've created an online form, and written the input values as a checkbox and text area. I've added a submit button to the form but when I click it, the data is not sent to the email address I've specified in the `form action` command. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <tr>
            <td>Please enter you're address and any further instruction.</td>
            <td><label for="delivery">Delivery Instructions</label></td>
            <td><textarea name="txtBody" id="Deliverybody" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
          <input type="submit" vlue="Submit Order" form action="mailto:me@hotmail.co.uk" method="post" name="neworder"/>
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to do a form in an email. [Here is a link](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-interactive-forms-in-email/) that you can use as a guide. If you still have questions then maybe you need to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for someone to help you. This is how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0):

It is a syntax error (check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp)), it should be

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Order" formaction="mailto:me@hotmail.co.uk" method="post" name="neworder"/>
```

Comment: I can't see what the difference is between the post I made and the answer you gave

Answer (score 0):

> Regards Of The Day

**The thing you are doing is absolutely wrong**

**This is not the way to be redirected to mail**

**You have to use anchor tag *(a tag)* for this**

**And this Code will not mail to your email it will redirect you to the mail and the user have to type himself in the mail**

**For directy mailing to your email you should know php**

*So Your Code Will Go Like This For Redirecting to the mail*

```
<a href="mailto:me@hotmail.co.uk" >
<button> Mail </button>
 </a>
```

Comment: Why would be PHP be useful when the anchor tag is included?

Comment: Because php can directly send e-mail to your mail

Comment: Under what instruction?

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like this is not possible. Sending an email needs an SMTP server. You need to have a server API to handle your request and send an email via an SMTP server.

However, you can get to prompt the users default email client when you want to send an email. Handle the `onSubmit` event of the form and run

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
```

Then call the following function

```
window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject=subject&body=body');
```

Here is a related post.

[create email form using html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885196/create-email-form-using-html)

Comment: What is an SMTP server?

Comment: A server which can send an email when you issue the command.

Comment: But is this not integrated as a server on the part of the host?

Answer (score 0):

Although not recommended to use this type of submissions a quick answer to your question is that your form should be captured inside a `<form> your fields  </form>` and the `form action` should be inside `<form class="" action:"mailto:me@gotmail.co.uk">` not on the `submit` button. However, do not use this on a live website! this is not the way to send emails! An example is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail) for your purpose.

Comment: Hi, why isn't it recommended, and why replace form action with form class. Shouldn't the form action be the solution

Answer (score -1):

=)

seems like everybody forgot emails don't support scripts because of safety.

so this won't work

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
```

```
form action="mailto:me@hotmail.co.uk"
```

but you can use forms in different ways in AMP emails.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail
(supported in Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook if I'm not wrong)