# html form to send email anonymously

Tags: html, survey

So what I'm looking to do is, make my feedback questionnaire send an anonymous email to my email with all the information in the form. WITHOUT requiring the user to have an outlook email. When the user hits submit the information should automatically send the input to the email provided.

here is a snippet of what i have

```
<form action="mailto:example@example.com" method="get" name="orderForm" target="_blank" enctype="text/plain">
    <fieldset tabindex="20">
        <legend> Please fill out the following form:  </legend><br>
        <div class="bordergreen">
            <div class="subheading"> Feedback Questionnaire </div> <hr>
            <label style="color: white;">1.) Was the overall layout ok for reading? </label>
            <textarea name="message" rows="5" co="30"> </textarea><br><br>
            <label style="color: white;">2.) Are the links easy to read and easy to   navigate? </label>
            <textarea name="message" rows="5" co="30"> </textarea><br>  <br>
            <label style="color: white;">3.) What are some things you would like to    change? </label>
            <textarea name="message" rows="5" co="30"> </textarea><br>    <br>
            <label style="color: white;">4.) Is the coloring appropriate or what     suggestions do you have? </label>
            <textarea name="message" rows="5" co="30">     </textarea><br><br>
            <label style="color: white;">5.) How is the font, style, and readibility?     </label>
            <textarea name="message" rows="5" co="30"> </textarea><br><br>
            <label> Would you recommend this site to others? </label><br><br>
            <label> Yes -------- </label> <input type="radio" name="recommend"><br>
            <label> No --------- </label> <input type="radio" name="recommend"><br>
            <label><button type="submit" style="float: right;"> Submit </button>    </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: This is absolutely not something html can do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send an HTML Form in an Email .. not just MAILTO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449767/how-do-i-send-an-html-form-in-an-email-not-just-mailto)

Comment: While not possible, this is still a perfectly fine question.

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: Use this script at your own risk. As it stands now it can be used by a malicious user to use your server for spam.

Post any suggestions or comments below.

File: send.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Send Anonymous Email</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
<form name="SAE" method="post" action="send.php">
<br>To Email: </br>
<br><input name="toemail" type="text" id="toemail" value=""></br>
<br>Subject: </br>
<br><input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" value=""></br>
<br>Message:</br>
<br> <textarea cols="50" rows="7" name="message"></textarea></br>
<br><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send!"></br>
<p>Powered by <a href="http://asian.sc">Anonymous Email Sender</a></p>
</body></html>
```

File: send.php

```
<?php

/*************************************************************************
*
*   Author   : Dennise Deno
*   Package  : Anonymous Email Sender
*   Version  : 0.1 Beta 2
*   Copyright: (C) 2021 Dennise Deno
*   Site     : www.ogonda.com
*   Email    : dennis[at]ogonda.com
*   File     : send.php
*
*   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
*   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
*   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
*   (at your option) any later version.
*
*   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
*   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
*   MERCHANT ABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
*   GNU General Public License for more details.
*
*************************************************************************/

$toemail = $_POST['toemail'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

mail($toemail, '$subject (Sent Anonymously)', "Hello,
The following is an anonymous email.

$message

Powered by http://ogonda.com - Anonymous Email Sender", 'From: '.$email);

echo "Thank you, $name<br>
Message sent to $toemail with the following information:</br>
Subject: $subject</br>
Message: $message</br>
<p>Powered by <a href=\"https://ogonda.com/\">Anonymous Email Sender</a></p>";?>
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Comment: This is an anonymous email script to be used in case you need a 'Whistle Blower' section in your HTML page. The two codes merged helps send the email and on your Admin side you get to receive the coded email from the anonymous sender.