# Sending an Email from an HTML form to my email

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, email

I am designing a website and my website has a form on it that includes name, email, and comment. I am looking to take that information after user hits the submit button and sending it to myself in an email. I have linked my HTML code below. Unfortunately for some reason I can not find anything on the internet.

```
<form>
          <h2>Send me a message!</h2>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Email" name>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Add Message"></textarea>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset">Reset</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: That's because you need to use a server-side language such as PHP to take the form data, process it, and send it as an email. You can't do this with client-side code.

Comment: You need server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment on the post already stated, the proper way to do it would require a backend (php, python, node, etc). However I just found a little workaround using google apps, it maye help you.

[Tutorial](https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server)

Taken from here: [Original answer/post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449767/how-do-i-send-an-html-form-in-an-email-not-just-mailto)