# how do I configure email on a contact form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I configure the email address for a contact form? I am using a template and have noob level knowledge of HTML and CSS and not much else. I would like to trace where I put my email address so that I start receiving emails via the form.

The HTML for the contact is

```
                    <div class="tab-entry">

                        <div class="row tab-entry-intro">
                        <div class="col-twelve with-bottom-line">



                        </div>          
                    </div> <!-- /tab-content-intro -->

                    <div class="row form-wrap tab-entry-content">
                        <div class="col-twelve">

                            <!-- form -->
                            <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="">
                                <fieldset>

                                  <div class="form-field">
                                           <input name="contactName" type="text" id="contactName" placeholder="Name" value="" minlength="2" required="">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-field">
                                       <input name="contactEmail" type="email" id="contactEmail" placeholder="Email" value="" required="">
                                   </div>
                                  <div class="form-field">
                                           <input name="contactSubject" type="text" id="contactSubject" placeholder="Subject" value="">
                                   </div>                       
                                  <div class="form-field">
                                        <textarea name="contactMessage" id="contactMessage" placeholder="message" rows="10" cols="50" required=""></textarea>
                                   </div>                      
                                 <div class="form-field">
                                     <button class="submitForm button button-primary large">Submit</button>

                                     <div id="submit-loader">
                                        <div class="text-loader">Sending...</div>                             
                                          <div class="s-loader">
                                                    <div class="bounce1"></div>
                                                    <div class="bounce2"></div>
                                                    <div class="bounce3"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div><!-- submit-loader -->
                                  </div>

                                </fieldset>
                            </form> <!-- /form -->

                            <!-- contact-warning -->
                            <div id="message-warning">              
                            </div>            
                            <!-- contact-success -->
                            <div id="message-success">
                               <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Your message was sent, thank you!<br>
                            </div>

                         </div> <!-- /col-twelve -->                            
                    </div> <!-- /row contact-form -->

                    </div> <!-- /tab-entry -->                  

                </div> <!-- /tab-contact -->
```

Comment: Don't make us go and chase down your code. Edit your question to include it here. Also, explain what you mean by "configure the email address". What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, but the question wouldn't let me explain what I wanted to do...whenever I tried it would not send. anyway, I'm very new and I'm using a template which I have customized for all else except the contact form... I have no idea how I get the form to actually direct emails to my address... where do I add it? I can see where the HTML code for the form is but that's it. I need to configure it.

Comment: Just hit the "edit" link below your question and add the relevant code (HTML and JS). We can't help you if you don't post your code and we do not go out to actual websites and view the source code of the page to find what code you are talking about. That's not how this site works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449767/how-do-i-send-an-html-form-in-an-email-not-just-mailto

Comment: thanks for this... Scott... really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seding an email directly with javascript (as it´s your tag)  is not possible, but you can open the user mail client:

window.open('mailto:name@domain.com');

It´s possible to have a predetermined subject and body using these variables:

window.open('mailto:name@domain.com?subject=example_subject&body=example_body');

Comment: Found a sendemail.php where I'm now searching for the correct place to insert the email... thanks for your help.

Comment: yes, with php is easy: mail(to,subject,message,headers)
but I thought you wanted to use javascript

Comment: The `mailto:` protocol is useless if the user uses web-based mail (GMail, Yahoo, etc.). Also, having an email in the HTML is just inviting spam.