# is it possible to send a html form with method post inside of an email?

Tags: html, forms, post, html-email

It's possible to insert a html form inside of an email template that works with method post? I mean inserting something like this inside of an email

```
<form action="test.com" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="1" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="test">
</form>
```

and make the form execute as post once you open the email and click on the test button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send an HTML Form in an Email .. not just MAILTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449767/how-do-i-send-an-html-form-in-an-email-not-just-mailto)

Comment: It is possible but will work on a bout 1 or 2 email clients