# How to make a html form email results

Tags: html

I made a html form and want it to email the results to me, so I can evaluate the answer and later add it to my website. i want the email to somewhat look like this:

name: *name*

email: *EMAIL*

title: *title*

messige: *massige*

current program:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</body>
  <form>
     name<br>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="user_input"><br>
    email<br>
     <input type="email" name="email" id="user_input"><br>
     title<br>
     <input type="text" name="title" id="user_input"><br>
     message<br>
     <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
  </form>
<div class="button">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send an HTML Form in an Email .. not just MAILTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449767/how-do-i-send-an-html-form-in-an-email-not-just-mailto)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use PHP/ Node.js/another technology, you can use the Formspree API. Your html would look like this:

```
<form action="https://formspree.io/your@email.com" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="email" name="_replyto">
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

And you sign up for an account here: https://formspree.io/ . You will receive form submissions in your inbox.

Another alternative is to add a "mailto" link instead of the full contact form. This creates a link that opens the user's default email system (ie gmail/outlook/mail) and lets them email you from their inbox. The "%0D%0A%0D%0A" part creates a new line in the email:

```
<a href="mailto:YOUREMAIL@gmail.com?subject=Hello&body=Hello Owen,%0D%0A%0D%0AI'm interested in xyz thing on your website%0D%0A%0D%0A" target="_blank">
```

Comment: i cant get it to work. sorry if my mistake is stupid. i'm new to programming. new program:<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    </body>
      <form action="https://formspree.io/myemal@icloud.com" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <input type="email" name="_replyto">
     <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
   <div class="button">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </div>
   </body>
   </html>

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</body>
  <form action="https://formspree.io/myemail@icloud.com" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="email" name="_replyto">
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<div class="button">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: First, initialize the form here, ie replace the placeholder with your email address in the html in the box on the left: https://test.formspree.io/ . Then copy-paste this into *your* html file, be sure to include the https:
        <form method="POST" action="https://formspree.io/YOUREMAIL@gmail.com">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Test Message"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Send Test</button>
      </form>

Comment: thanks! i'v updated my screen name, so can fix the name in your comments?

Comment: @catlover done and done. Remember to upvote answers if they helped 